# ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

Tags: ansible

I've got an error with Ansible, that I don't understand:

`ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable`

It happens in in role where I call a var file:

```
- name: import pdt vars
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ pdt_type }}.yml"
```

The "{{ pdt_type }}.yml" contains:

```
pdt_pkg:
  - { name: "zzz-libs" }
  - { name: "zzz-core" }
```

What is wrong with that? Is it really a bug?

Comment: It certainly appears you have left off key pieces of your setup, including contextual text that appeared before that error message. Please also pay attention to the [MCVE section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it's designed to help you troubleshoot as much as helping us with relevant details

Answer (score -1):

The `{ }` is supposed to declare a dictionary, using a [flow collection syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics)

You seem to declare two dictionaries, each with the same key "`name`"

Check if the content if  `{{ pdt_type }}.yml` is actually the issue, by using a simpler content:

```
pdt_pkg:
  - name1: "zzz-libs"
  - name2: "zzz-core"
```